# TableAdapter not updating in-memory values in DataTable

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, tableadapter, database-concurrency

I have a TableAdapter with a designer-built `.Update()` command. The TableAdapter also has a command which will update just one of the fields in one of the records. This command is `.AddBankName`.

However `.AddBankName` appears to be causing `.Update()` to throw a Concurrency violation. This is only happening if `.AddBankName` is actually *changing* the BankName field in the DB.

So what I presume is happening is that the `AddBankName` query in the TableAdapter is not updating the in memory record of the database table which the TableAdapter maintains.

How can I make `AddBankName` do the correct update. Or - how do I do it myself?

This is an excerpt of my code. `UpdateDB` can be called multiple times...

```
Sub UpdateDB()
    'This Update will fail if AddBankName has previously changed BankName
    LETTERINFORMATIONTableAdapter.Update(tblTECHLETTERINFORMATION)

    LETTERINFORMATIONTableAdapter.AddBankName(cmbBANKNAME.Text, _ 
       txtCLIENTNUMBER.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the SQL you are using inside AddBankName to update the database look like?

Comment: It's very basic such as `UPDATE LETTERINFORMATION SET BANKNAME=? WHERE ID=?`